# ¿Como hacer que no salga una excepción cuando deje los texfield vacios?

Tags: java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando quiero poner en el combobox una operación sin que ponga los valores me aparece una excepción(number format exception) y después de eso aunque ponga valores en los textfield ya no me deja hacer las operaciones, quisiera saber como puedo hacer que no deje hacer la operación si deja los espacios en blanco.

```
int res=0;
int i=Cmboperacion.getSelectedIndex();  
   intval1=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(txtval1.getText()));

intval2=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(txtval2.getText()));

        if(txtval1.getText().isEmpty() || txtval2.getText().isEmpty())
        {
            Cmboperacion.setVisible(false);
        }
        else
        {
            Cmboperacion.setVisible(true);
            if(i == 0)
        {
            res=val1+val2;
        }
        else if(i == 1)
        {
            res=val1-val2;
        }
        else if(i == 2)
        {
            res=val1*val2;
        }
        else if(i == 3)
        {
            try
            {
                if((val1 == 0 && val2 == 0)||val1==0||val2==0)
                {
                lblexception.setText("Error");
                }
                else
                {
                    res=val1/val2;
                }
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                res=val1/val2;
            }
           }
            txtres.setText(String.valueOf(res));
        }
```

Comment: ¿Qué problema tiene ese código?

Comment: Cuando quiero poner en el combobox una operación sin que ponga los valores me aparece una excepción(number format exception) y después de eso aunque ponga valores en los textfield ya no me deja hacer las operaciones, quisiera saber como puedo hacer que no deje hacer la operación si deja los espacios en blanco.

Comment: En qué linea te aparece la excepción?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en que estás asumiendo que los campos de texto tienen valor antes de comprobar si están vacíos:

```
intval1=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(txtval1.getText()));
intval2=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(txtval2.getText()));
```

Estas dos líneas van a darte una excepción si `txtval1` o `txtval2` están vacíos.
O metes esas dos líneas en un `try-catch` para capturar la posible excepción, o no haces la conversión a entero sin comprobar que `getText()` te devuelva vacío.